# dynamic height with absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I have a more complex solution which I reduced for sample:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="top_bar" style="position:fixed;width:100%;background-color:red;"> 
        <div style="position: relative; width:200px;height: 50px;background-color:black;"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="navigation_bar" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:30px; background-color:orange;width:200px"> 
        <ul>
            <li>Menu 1</li>
            <li>Menu 2</li>
            <li>Menu 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="position:absolute;left:200px;top:30px; bottom:0;right:0">
        <div  style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0; bottom:0;right:0;background-color: blue">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/DC51eyvQJVuIlPyiQIr4?p=preview

Basically, I have a top bar, a left bar and some content in html. The problem is top bar height is not fixed (as it is set in my example), and I want the left bar and content to start after end of top bar. In sample the content/left bar overlap the top bar which should not happen, those should be one after the other. Any ideas how can I fix this (would prefer minimum code changes)?

Answer (score 1):

You can easilly achieve this in jquery like so :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var height = $("#top_bar").css("height");
    $("#navigation_bar").css("top", height);
    $("#content").css("top", height);

});
```

If you don't want to use jquery. You should not use position absolute to make your layout. If you just want a fixed top bar there many other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could always add some pixels to the `top`-property of the `navigation_bar` and `content` divs, in your case 58px instead of 30px. But this method is not really sustainable since you'd have to add the `top`-property to everything beneath your `top_bar`. A better solution would be to place the `navigation_bar` and `content` in a wrapper that has `top: 58px` and then the content in the wrapper wouldn't need to be styled with `position: relative`.

Comment: The problem is the 50 px height is really dynamic (that is a toolbar that has variable number of items). So, this is why cannot use top declaration in this case. I am looking for a way to fix this without having to change my whole layout.